# Bug display with react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I start with react and I want to use a module that is called "react-leaflet" to make a map map.
But the problem is that I have a display bug with my map in the end on my page.
Can you help me please ?

Component Map:

```
import './Map.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

export default class MapLeaflet extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: 51.505,
            lng: -0.09,
            zoom: 13
        }
    }

    render() {
        const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
        console.log("dqdsqdq");
        return(
            <div id="map">
                <Map center={position} zoom={13}>
                    <TileLayer
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                    />
                    <Marker position={position}>
                        <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
                    </Marker>
                </Map>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Page to display Map:

```
import './Apies.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MapLeaflet from '../../components/Map/Map.js';

export default class Apies extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="Apies">
                <main className="main">
                    <h2>Map</h2>
                    <MapLeaflet/>
                </main>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Bug display: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb7fH.jpg

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, I don't have any error in my console

Comment: Have you set a height to your map or have you imported leaflet.css? Try `<Map style={{height: '100vh'}} center={position} zoom={13}>`

Comment: No, I do not know how to import the leaflet css. And I tried your order that has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required to import leaflet.css in your index.js and give a height to map container.

index.js:

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

MapLeaflet:

```
  ...
<Map style={{ height: "100vh" }} center={position} zoom={13}>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xry0057z6w)

Comment: Thank you I try this tomorrow and I'll let you know the result

Comment: Sure. No problem

Comment: Thx you, it works but i don't see my marker. I have two error in my console. Error "data:image/png;base64, marker-icon.png:1" and "data:image/png;base64, marker-shadow.png:1"

Comment: I updated the demo link. Check now and please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: confirmed works! i did not have the height specified and did not have the css imported. thank you!